# finetuned quantum experiments by Murch lab, do any have dynamics outside of basic QM formalism/ axioms?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics, quantum-interpretations, measurement-problem, foundations

a series of very finetuned quantum experiments have been reported by the [Murch lab](http://murch.physics.wustl.edu/) eg in 2 articles in Nature & analysis there,[1][2][3] some leading to dramatic accounts in the media.[4]

> do any of these experiments observe phenomena that are not fully explainable by or "outside of" the standard QM theoretical/ mathematical formalism/ axioms? if so can this particular effect be contrasted/ highlighted/ pinpointed (eg wrt QM)?

[1] [Observing single quantum trajectories of a superconducting quantum bit](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v502/n7470/full/nature12539.html) / K. W. Murch,  S. J. Weber,    C. Macklin  & I. Siddiqi

[2] [Mapping the optimal route between two quantum states](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v511/n7511/full/nature13559.html) / S. J. Weber,    A. Chantasri,   J. Dressel, A. N. Jordan,   K. W. Murch & I. Siddiqi

[3] [Quantum physics: Watching the wavefunction collapse](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v502/n7470/full/502177a.html) / Jordan

[4] [Can the past be changed by the FUTURE? Bizarre quantum experiment suggests time can run backwards](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-2946445/Can-past-changed-FUTURE-Bizarre-quantum-experiment-suggests-time-run-backwards.html) / DailyMail

Comment: we are not able to understand what the article proves, and **if** it proves something, by merely reading the title. Not everybody has access to those journals, and nobody will buy those article for answering you. They cost money. You get the articles, and then we'll have the possibility to inspect them. About "past be changed by future" I am afraid that in the microscopic world past and future aren't well defined, exactly as in the relativity the past and future depend on the frame of coordinates. But, show us the articles.

Comment: lol presumably real experts in QM esp in foundations or interpretations will be interested & the effects are also said to have applications in quantum computing etc. here is one of the papers on arxiv, forgot to cite it, [Prediction and retrodiction for a continuously monitored superconducting qubit](http://lanl.arxiv.org/pdf/1409.0510.pdf) Weber et al, others may be on arxiv also...

Comment: Now it's late in my country. Let's see tomorrow. But, as I said, past and future aren't absolute, in QM, s.t. we may say in certain circumstances that the future influences the past. The quantum world is very counter-intuitive.

Comment: short comment: The authors don't claim physics beyond QM and I don't see any - I'm far from an experimentalist though and one always has to be very careful when interpreting experiments. However, this here: http://arxiv.org/abs/0707.3880 seems to be somewhat similar to [3] and has lots of discussions, e.g. here http://scienceblogs.com/principles/2007/09/12/watching-wavefunctions-collaps/